# 画面が閉じられるイベントの察知方法を教えてください。

Tags: javascript, jquery

皆様いつも御世話になっております。
JQuery・JavaScriptのいづれかで、自画面が閉じられるイベントの察知方法を教えてくださいませんか？
この察知を行った中で

```
//親画面で無効化したイメージボタンを有効化
window.opener.$(".cdsrch").prop("disabled", false);
```

を達成したいです。

あるデータ受付用の画面はTableの明細を有しており、その各々1列目にコード検索画面を開くためのボタンを配置しています。この押下をもって子画面イメージのコード検索画面をJSでwindow.openしています。
その際、元画面の全明細の例のボタンをdisableすることで、子画面が2つ以上呼ばれないような工夫を行っています。
子画面側である程度の動作（リストボックスからの選択）が行われれば、当該子画面を閉じると同時に元画面でdisableにしたボタンを再度有効化しているのが現況です。
これ故．．．
現況は、コード検索の子画面を右上×ボタンで閉じられてしまうと、親画面のdisableにしたボタンが有効に戻っていない！という状態です。

***PS***
そもそも親画面のJQueryで、子画面が閉じられたら？という察知を図るべきなのでしょうか？
その察知方法も分かりませんが．．．．

ご見解を頂けましたら幸いです、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unload`イベントが使えると思います。
以下は実装サンプルです。

```
// 子画面
$(window).on('unload', function() {
    window.opener.exports.onChildWindowClosed();
});

// 親画面
window.exports = {
    onChildWindowClosed: function() {
        $('.cdsrch').prop('disabled', false);
    }
};
```

Comment: 早速のご支援誠にありがとうございます。本当に初心者で教えて頂いた内容を理解できない自分がいるのですが、
２つ記載頂いている理由には、①子画面が閉じられたことを親画面に知らせている
②親画面側の挙動で、該当ボタンの再度有効化を果たそうとしている、ということでしょうか？

子画面自身が閉じられたことを$(window).on('unload', function() {で察知できるのなら、この中に
window.opener.$(".cdsrch").prop("disabled", false);
を記載すればいいのでは？？？と単純に考えてしまったのですが．．．。ま、試してみればよいのですかね

Comment: この度はご支援ありがとうございました。
やはり当方の推察どおり、子画面自体のJS（unloadの察知部分）で
親画面側のボタン再有効化を試行してみたところ、無事希望の動作を達成することができました。

Comment: はい、それでも構いませんよ。ただ私としては、disableにするボタンは親ページに有るので、それらを制御するコードも親ページにあるほうが自然かなと思いました。

Answer (score 1):

参考までに、window.open時に親側でイベント登録のサンプルコードを書いてみました。
（IEでは動作確認していませんので参考まで。）

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var co_window = window.open('test.html','test','width=600,height=600');
    co_window.addEventListener('load',function(event){
        console.log('open');
        co_window.addEventListener('unload',function(event){
            console.log('close');
        }, false);
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: いつもご親切なご支援をありがとうございます。
itmammothさんもyyzさんも親画面側での動作を推奨しているように受けてとれ
子画面で察知と動作を達成してしまう方法がなんかアブノーマルなことなのかな？？
と思い始めています。itmammothさんのコメントに返信していますが、一応無事動作は
達成している模様ですが弱冠心配．．．．自分は経験が薄く

Comment: いわゆる「凝集度」の問題だと思います。ある画面の内容を制御するコードが別の画面にあると（そういうコーディングを許すと）、その画面の制御がどこに実装されているのか、アプリケーション全体を意識しなければならなくなります（凝集度が低くなっている状態）。「このボタン、勝手にdisabledが変更されるけど、どこに実装されているんだ？」と思った時、まずどこのソースを見るでしょうか？　どこに書かれていると見つけやすいでしょうか？　という問題です。